# Is there any way to cancel a click event in datagrid view in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` and I use `CellClick` event.

```
if(datagridview.Row[e.rowindex].Cells["column1"].value.ToString()=="something")
 {
   // How can I cancel the click event here  ??
 }
```

Comment: return didn't work for me

Comment: What do you what to achieve and what do you mean by canceling?

Answer (score 0):

1st way to do this:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Column1"].Selected = false;
```

2nd way:

```
dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Selected = false;
```

You can use both ways to cancel the selection of the cell.